# Retrieve records from one table related to another depending on certain criteria

Tags: sql

I need your SQL assistance please.
I have one table which has unique id's and is used as a reference in a second and third table. The second table can have multiple entries for the reference id. I however only wish to retrieve the id's and details from the second table, where the reference in the third table is the same, but all the records in the second table don't have the same description.

Example: (Simplified)
Table1: (object_id is auto-increment and always unique)

```
-------------------------------
|  object_id  |  object_name  |
-------------------------------
|     1234    |      Julian   |
-------------------------------
|     1235    |      Adrian   |
-------------------------------
|     1236    |      Sarah    |
-------------------------------
|     1237    |      Julian   |
-------------------------------
|     1238    |      Julian   |
-------------------------------
```

Table 2: (object_id is referenced to Table 1 object_id, but account_no can be anything

```
-------------------------------
|  object_id  |  account_no   |
-------------------------------
|     1234    |      1111     |
-------------------------------
|     1234    |      2222     |
-------------------------------
|     1235    |      3333     |
-------------------------------
|     1236    |      4444     |
-------------------------------
|     1236    |      5555     |
-------------------------------
|     1237    |      1111     |
-------------------------------
|     1238    |      1111     |
-------------------------------
```

Table 3: (object_id is referenced to Table 1 object_id, but property_id should be the same for a specific account_no)

```
-------------------------------
|  object_id  |  property_id  |
-------------------------------
|     1234    |      house_1  |
-------------------------------
|     1235    |      house_15 |
-------------------------------
|     1236    |      house_7  |
-------------------------------
|     1236    |      house_7  |
-------------------------------
|     1237    |      house_2  |
-------------------------------
|     1238    |      house_1  |
-------------------------------
```

So the extract I need is all the rows from Table 3 where the property_id is not the same for a given account_no from table 2, with the object_id and object_name from Table 1.

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  object_id  |  object_name  |  account_no   |  property_id  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|     1234    |      Julian   |      1111     |      house_1  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|     1237    |      Julian   |      1111     |      house_2  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|     1238    |      Julian   |      1111     |      house_1  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the account number is the one that links the records, but they are all referenced to object_id for the property_id. I need all the records for the accounts where the property_id doesn't match, the ones with single property_id's or where there are multiple account_no but the same property_id can be ignored.

So to get all the info it would be something like:

```
SELECT ob.object_id, ob.object_name, ac.account_no, pr.property_id
FROM Table1 AS ob
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS ac ON ob.object_id = ac.object_id
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS pr ON ob.object_id = pr.object_id
```

This would return all the rows linking the account_no and the property_id to the object_id, but I only want the ones returned where the property_id don't match for a given account_no.

I have tried joins and exists and various options, but I am unable to figure this one out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to determine when the values are not all the same:

```
select object_id, object_name, account_no, property_id
from (select t1.object_id, t1.object_name, t2.account_no, t3.property_id,
             min(t3.property_id) over (partition by t1.object_name, t2.account_no) as min_pi,
             max(t3.property_id) over (partition by t1.object_name, t2.account_no) as max_pi
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t2.object_id = t1.object_id join
           table3 t3
           on t3.object_id = t1.object_id
     ) t
where min_pi <> max_pi;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, The SQL returns no rows. i fi remove the "where min_pi <> max_pi", then it returns all the rows, but the where clause doesn't seem to return the different rows with different property id's. We do seem to be on the right track though.

Comment: @EDWOZ . . . `object_id` should not be in the `partition by`.  I see it changes on every row.